# CSS Stylesheets on EWW

Tags: eww, web-browser, css

Began here on using `eww` as web browser in Emacs, but felt that it misses `CSS` stylish, even loading simple `HTML` and `CSS` only.

Already managed to repair `libxml2` error before running it, but now would like to load `CSS` stylish, like divisions, body, main or footer styling, for example.

How could that be done?

Comment: By "stylish" I assume you mean "stylesheets" (or perhaps just "styles") ?

Comment: Meant to display content effectively divided on the screen, as `#body`, `#container`, `#header`, `#footer`, instead of scrambled content as currently shows.

Comment: Already corrected it @phils.

Comment: eww has minimal support for stylesheets, what you ask for cannot be done this way.